# SQLServer The definition of object 'name' has changed since it was compiled

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm getting an error after updating a procedure and executing it.

> The definition of object 'PROCEDURE NAME' has changed
>   since it was compiled.

Is there a fix for this error ?

Comment: What sort of object is OBJECT NAME, and what is its relation to the procedure you are executing?

Comment: Object Name refers to the procedure name. Ill update the main post to reflect this too. Regarding the relation; the same procedure I am updating I am also executing.

Comment: Are you changing the procedure in one window and executing it in another?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. I'm updating it in SSMS and executing a separate application which calls the procedure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you changing the procedure in one window and executing it in
another?

> Yes, this is the case. I'm updating it in SSMS and executing a
>   separate application which calls the procedure

You need to end the session in which you are editing the procedure. The changes are only visible in the editing session until they are committed.

Comment: There is also the case where the SP stays in memory within the same connection session but you change target DBs. The DBs need to have the same build for the SP, so you need to be sure if you change something on the SP the 'new' version needs to be deployed on all DBs that are used in the connection session.

Answer (score 3):

I've just encountered another situation where this can happen, and I thought I'd mention it here, in case it helps anyone else.

I had an "after update" trigger, in which I was updating a datetime [DateModified] column. I didn't want this trigger to trigger other triggers on the same table, so I was doing this within the trigger...

```
disable trigger all on [MyTable];
```

Of course what I overlooked was that this also disabled the currently running trigger, and resulted in the error...

```
The definition of object 'MyTrigger' has changed since it was compiled.
```

The solution was to explicitly list the triggers I need to disable, rather than using 'all'.